# How to display dialog after current dialog in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I hava an array like this

```
export const activities = [
  {
    title: "Take the Stairs",
    progressOverview: {
      notSatisfied: 5,
      neutral: 0,
      satisfied: 2,
    },
  },
  {
    title: "5 Set of Sit-Ups",
    progressOverview: {
      notSatisfied: 3,
      neutral: 2,
      satisfied: 5,
    },
  },
  {
    title: "3 Sets of Push-Ups",
    progressOverview: {
      notSatisfied: 7,
      neutral: 3,
      satisfied: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    title: "Weight Lifting",
    progressOverview: {
      notSatisfied: 3,
      neutral: 2,
      satisfied: 0,
    },
  },
]
```

And. I have a dialog/modal like this
[image]

Now I want to display every `title` in array to show in the `activities` that dialog (in this pic is `abc`), it mean when I click `save`. (It mean `next`) it will display all activities one by one until last item, and in the last item I want to have other dialog, How can I do that? All item is the same, except the last one